# Are these two complements?

Tags: past-participles, deverbal

> For one thing, when Seamus Finnigan asked eagerly to hear how Quirrell
>   had fought off the zombie, Quirrell went pink and started talking
>   about the weather; for another, they had noticed that a funny smell
>   hung around the turban, and the Weasley twins insisted that **it was
>   stuffed full of garlic** as well, so that Quirrell was protected
>   wherever he went. 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

In the sentence highlighted, do we see complement plus complement - [stuffed][full of garlic], or link-like verbs plus compliment – [was stuffed][full of garlic], or others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Stuffed* is one of those awkward participles, like *confused* or *convinced* that is halfway to being a "deverbal" adjective.

I frankly don't know how you draw the line. I'm inclined to say it's still a participle if it takes a complement. For instance, in

> I'm convinced that Homer was a woman

*convinced* is a participle. Likewise, *stuffed* here is a participle. But in

> I'm stuffed (*colloquial for "I've eaten too much"*)

*stuffed* is an adjective.

But I don't think it matters. I think the distinction between *verb* and *adjective* here is an artificial one.

A *participle*, after all, is called that because it *participates* in both verbal and adjectival uses at the same time, and I don't think that changes when the verbal use is called a "passive construction".

Comment: Can I accept that the participle, stuffed, has its complement, full of garlic?

Comment: @Listenever That's how I'd read it: [Subject: *someone*] ***stuffed** [Direct Object:*it*] [Secondary/Object Complement: *full of garlic*]